# Experienced shade tree mechanic needs ideas to speed up shop times

Tags: oil-change

I've been an under the table mechanic for quite a while. finally broke into the field via the quicklane at a dealership. Tons of advancement opportunity!

So I'm reaching out to others who have more shop experience than myself.

I'm wondering how to organize my routine for checking fluids, setting up car on lift, rotating tires, drain oil/filter, replace plug/filter, multipoint inspection, etc...

I do not want to be a disorganized tech! I see it a lot and that's not for me. My box is organized, and I have the right tools, like I said just need help working out a routine that will save time and multitask all the things I need to do. Ideally lowering the overall time the vehicle is away from it's owner.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Things like don’t stand watching the oil drain, get on with other bits...

Comment: I hate to say it but this really is too broad, and also opinion based. It can't be definitively answered.

Comment: Do like all the other quick lubes do, skip some of the checks....

Comment: GD: I wasn't asking for a definitive answer. My wording was probably off. I was more interested in other people's routines and setups, something to base my own off of. Maybe any tips that anyone has learned from their experience. I know how to do the work, I'm just not used to the shop environment, turning hours and such.

Comment: Moab: HA! I see those guys at the shop im at. Doing MPI's playing on their cellphones. My goal is to get to the main shop, not stay in quick Lane for life!

Answer (score 2):

If you're at a OE dealership the tools will be common across models. Get a service cart if you don't have one. It'll save time walking back and forth to your box.

I'd be less concerned about being quick and multitasking. More about making sure you hit all the checks on the sheet. Once you find a routine that works for the shop SOP you'll gradually get faster at doing things.

Quick example...

Prepare the stuff you need before hand. Fluids, filters, etc...

Do what makes sense, once the car's in the air you can check the tires, check the suspension, pull the tires, check brakes, etc...

Drain your oil, pull the filter, check any other undercar stuff you need to do in the air.

Lower the car, torque your wheels, do your engine bay fluids, lube the hinges and latches and ship it.